# selective display of spines

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I set up a plot of my dataframe with a subplot of each column, where the index is plotted on the y-axis and shared among the subplots.

I am trying to only display the left spines of the first (leftmost) and the right spines of the last (rightmost) subplot. I know, I can switch them on and off using e.g. `ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)`, but that always applies to all spines.

I am iterating over the columns to create the subplots. Is there a way to iterate over those to selectively display the splines? Or any other way, really?

Here is my MWE using dummy data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))


fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=len(df.columns), sharey=True)
fig.set_size_inches(7, 4)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.25)


for col, ax in zip(df.columns, axs.flatten()):
    ax.plot(df[col], df.index, label=col)
    ax.set_xlabel(col)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

which gives me the following figure:[dummyplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KiVw.png)

I started out trying something like this:

```
for ax.spines[-1] in ax.spines:
        ax.spines['right'].set_visible(True)
```

which doesn't work of course, but might help illustrate what I am looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be to hide the right and left spines for all subplots, and then re-enable the two you want to display:

```
for col, ax in zip(df.columns, axs.flatten()):
    ax.plot(df[col], df.index, label=col)
    ax.set_xlabel(col)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

axs[0].spines['left'].set_visible(True)
axs[-1].spines['right'].set_visible(True)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, this certainly works, As the ncols is likely to change I have implemented ```axs[len(df.columns)-1].spines['right'].set_visible(True)``` to keep it somewhat dynamic. Thanks!